# Best way to code multiple decisions in Python

Tags: python, django, if-statement

I have the following practical problem (related to Django/Python).

I'm trying to get the following in the most efficient piece of Python code ->

There are 2 items to be checked:

1. Is the user logged in? if not show a login page, else check if the request is a post request.
2. Is the request a post request? If not show a form, else handle the form

   ```
   def upload(request):
   if request.user.is_authenticated:
       if request.method == 'POST':
           form = forms.DocumentForm()
           return HttpResponse('Handle POST and LoggedIn Prefix Form Validation')
       else:
           return HttpResponse('POST but not logged in')
           return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': form}
   else:
       return HttpResponse('Not Logged In Need to Make Error Landing Page')
   ```

Comment: Two if-else statements are very efficient. Is there any specific reason you're unhappy with the performance of the code?

Comment: Fix indendation...

Comment: @Jonas I was/am not sure about the last Else statement. But reading your comment the current code will do the job?

Comment: Yes, current code will be about as efficient as you're going to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this is quite pythonic...

```
def upload(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        #return early
        return HttpResponse('Not Logged In Need to Make Error Landing Page')

    # this will only be reached if user authenticated
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.DocumentForm()
        return HttpResponse('Handle POST and LoggedIn Prefix Form Validation')
    else:
        pass # handle GET
```

If you need to check the authentication in multiple functions, consider using a decorator instead

```
@authenticated_users_only(request)
def upload(request):   
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.DocumentForm()
        return HttpResponse('Handle POST and LoggedIn Prefix Form Validation')
    else:
        pass # handle GET
```

If you don't know how to write a decorator yet - [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-to-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators/1594484#1594484)

Answer (score 0):

Avoid `else` when possible and use **early return**:

```
def upload(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method != 'POST':
            return HttpResponse('Not Logged In Need to Make Error Landing Page')
        form = forms.DocumentForm()
        return HttpResponse('Handle POST and LoggedIn Prefix Form Validation')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        return HttpResponse('POST but not logged in')
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful hint here. Read some about early return and it obviously clarifies a lot.